# Passing parameter to Wordpress do_action function through $_POST variable value

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post, plugins, action

I've got an action handler in my plugin which catches a form being posted to admin-ajax.php. The action namespace is 'handle_custom_form_submission'.

I can easily pass arguments to my action handlers in php via the do_action( 'namespace', 'argument' ) function; However, if I'm catching an action via AJAX, all I can do, to my knowledge, is have a $_POST var whose name="action" and value="namespace". Is there any way to pass a parameter into my action call this way? Like

```
<input name="action" value="handle_custom_form_submission( 'a' )"/>
```

Here's the situation in more detail:

I'm trying to write a custom form plugin so that I can easily handle multiple unique forms on a Wordpress site.

On my latest project, I've got a contact form on one page, and a testimonial submission form on another. In my code, I'm just designating them as 'custom-form-a' and 'custom-form-b'.

I've got 3 main action hooks:

1. include_custom_form_js( $form_id )
2. include_custom_form_html( $form_id )
3. handle_custom_form_submission()

I'd like to be able to pass #3, handle_custom_form_submission(), a $form_id as well. The only thing I can think of right now is to declare two seperate functions, handle_custom_form_a_submission() and handle_custom_form_b_submission(). Is there a cleaner way?

My main plugin file:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Form
Plugin URI: 
Description: Add custom form HTML and handle its submission on the backend.
Version: 0.1
Author: James Heston
*/

require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/php/constants.php' );

class CustomForm{

  // paths
  private $plugin_dir = CUSTOMFORM_DIRNAME;
  private $plugin_path = CUSTOMFORM_URLPATH;

  // action names
  private $action_include_js = 'include_custom_form_js';
  private $action_include_html = 'include_custom_form_html';
  private $action_handle_submission = 'handle_custom_form_submission';

  // other vars
  private $recipient_email = ''; // probably should pull from some WP option



  public function __construct(){
    $this->add_hooks();
  }

  private function add_hooks(){
    // include necessary js with appropriate MyAjax properties on page where `do_action( 'include_custom_form_js', $form_id )` action is called
    add_action( $this->action_include_js, array( $this, $this->action_include_js ), 10, 1 );
    // include form html on page where `do_action( 'include_custom_form_html', $form_id )` action is called
    add_action( $this->action_include_html, array( $this, $this->action_include_html ), 10, 1 );
    // handle contact form submission
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $this->action_handle_submission, array( $this, $this->action_handle_submission ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $this->action_handle_submission, array( $this, $this->action_handle_submission ) ); 
  }

  function include_custom_form_js( $form_id ){    

    wp_enqueue_script(
      $this->action_include_js,
      $this->plugin_path . '/js/custom-form-' . $form_id . '.js',
      array(),
      false,
      true
    );
    $localize_array = array(
      'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      'namespace' => $this->action_handle_submission
    );
    wp_localize_script( $this->action_include_js, 'MyAjax', $localize_array );
  }

  function include_custom_form_html( $form_id ){    
    include( $this->plugin_dir . '/html/custom-form-' . $form_id . '.html' );
  }  

  function handle_custom_form_submission(){
    $form_id = 'a';
    include( $this->plugin_dir . '/php/handle-custom-form-' . $form_id . 'submission.php' );
    include( $this->plugin_dir . '/php/handle-custom-form-' . $form_id . 'submission.php' );
  }

  function send_email(){
    // 
  }

  static function instance(){
    global $CustomForm;
    if(! isset($CustomForm) ){
      $CustomForm = new CustomForm();
    }
  }

}// class CustomForm

if(! isset($CustomForm) ){
  CustomForm::instance(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind, add an additional input field to the form specifying whether its 'a' or 'b'. Like `<input type="hidden" name="form-type" value="a">`, then in the receiving function check the value in `$_POST['form-type']`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have going on as of now. Was hoping there was a way to pass in both the action call and it's argument as 1 $_POST value.